# Multiple lines when using jQuery's .html method

Tags: jquery

I would like to have multiple lines when I use jQuery's html method, like this:

```
$("#someID").html("
    <h1>Headline 1</h1>
    <h1>Headline 2</h1>
    ");
```

However this snippet of code does not work. Is there a way to use multiple lines when using jQuery's html method?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You could use string concatenation to join the new lines. Its clean too.

```
$("#someID").html("" +
    "<h1>Headline 1</h1>" +
    "<h1>Headline 2</h1>");
```

Comment: better solution if getting multiple lines from say ajax response.

Answer (score 66):

use `\` to escape new line chars.

```
$("#someID").html("\
    <h1>Headline 1</h1>\
    <h1>Headline 2</h1>\
    ");
```

View working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/amantur/yeDff/

Comment: while concatenation is clean, this is to me much cleaner as only need to worry about opening `"` and closing `"`

Answer (score 15):

It's a bit late but now can do even cleaner:

```
$("#someID").html(`
    <h1>Headline 1</h1>
    <h1>Headline 2</h1>
    `);
```

And you can even add variables without concatenation:

```
$("#someID").html(`
    <h1>${headline1}</h1>
    <h1>${headline2}</h1>
    `);
```