# I want to use a big html code in jquery

Tags: jquery

In particular, method .append(html). How I can add big html code in append, for example:

```
$("#results").append('<div class="some class"> ...a lot of html code... </div>')
```

Comment: What's the problem using `append()`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676990/multiple-lines-when-using-jquerys-html-method or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8277462/jquery-append-external-html-file-into-my-page   ... depending on what you trying to do

Comment: i think it is not correct for use a lot of html code in append, and it is not confortable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store it in a html file on your server such as 'template.html' and load it in:

$( "#results" ).load( "/template.html" );

That will work if the html is static, but that begs the question, why can't you just show and hide a div on your page that contains the html.

But I'm guessing you have a lot more jQuery inserting values in to the html before you append it to #results, if so maybe you could use something like https://github.com/janl/mustache.js

Hope this helps.